# Filtering by attribute

Tags: xquery

Below is a excerpt from a XML file with 65 lectures:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
   <university>
    <lecture>
        <class>English</class>
        <hours>3</hours>
        <pupils>30</pupils>
    </lecture>
    <lecture>
        <class>Math</class>
        <hours>4</hours>
        <pupils>27</pupils
    </lecture>
    <lecture>
        <class>Science</class>
        <hours>2</hours>
        <pupils>25</pupils>
    </lecture>
   </university>
```

I need a where clause that gives me a list of lectures with more pupils than an English lecture. However, not with the attribute "30" used, but calling the English's lecture attribute instead

E.g., I want to use a where clause with a condition like **pupils > English.pupils**, instead of **pupils > 30**.

(The "pupils > English.pupils" is just puesdo code as an example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `where` clause isn't strictly necessary, but to use one you would make it part of a `for` iterator:

```
let $lectures := doc("lectures.xml")/university/lecture
let $english-pupils := $lectures[class = "English"]/pupils/xs:integer(.)
for $lecture in $lectures
where ($lecture/pupils/xs:integer(.) gt $english-pupils)
return $lecture
```

You could also avoid the `flwor` altogether by using an XPath predicate.

```
let $lectures := doc("lectures.xml")/university/lecture
let $english-pupils := $lectures[class = "English"]/pupils/xs:integer(.)
return $lectures[pupils/xs:integer(.) gt $english-pupils]
```

Comment: thanks, i'm currently using a for loop so that's okay. I see you declared the english pupils in the let, as well as the general lectures. However, in the where clause, does the gt mean "over"? So, does line 4 mean "_pupils > English.pupils_"?

Comment: `gt` simply means "greater than". If you are comparing sequences you would use `>`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Both code works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A sequence is how XQuery handles more than one item, as opposed to other languages that have arrays. If either side of the comparison is a sequence then you would use `>` instead of `gt`.